# Fabric export report does not have user id

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I am using Crashlytics for fatal and non-fatal event reporting.

Also setting user info on Crashlytics. When Crash is reported, I can see user info is visible on fabric dashboard along with device statistics, but when I download .txt of crash stack trace, It has everything like device,ram etc but not user info. Am I missing anything?

Exporting crash report : https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/export-crash-report.html